# Semicolon on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following jQuery works with or without a semicolon after the function. Why?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#red").treeview({
    animated: "fast",
    collapsed: true,
    control: "#treecontrol",
    persist: "cookie"
})

});
```

It works on all browsers. Wouldn't this cause an error?

Comment: Why should it? Semicolons are optional (at least at this position).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't actually require semicolons.  That's just convention.

http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons

I recommend using semicolons, just like I'd recommend indenting your code.